# Get the list of selected terms select option dropdown

Tags: wordpress

Can you help me!
I using wordpress 
Example:
I have taxonomy: department

- Term have posts name: Cardiac Clinic (doctor 1, doctor 2, doctor 3)
- Term have posts name: Gynaecological Clinic(doctor 4, doctor 5)

I want 
When I choose Cardiac Clinic then show dropdown

```
<select>
<option>doctor 1</option>
<option>doctor 2</option>
<option>doctor 3</option>
</select>
```

and 
When I choose Gynaecological Clinic then show dropdown

```
<select>
<option>doctor 4</option>
<option>doctor 5</option>
</select>
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$post_type = 'event-posts';
$customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);
if(count($customPostTaxonomies) > 0)
 {
  foreach($customPostTaxonomies as $tax)
  {
     $args = array(
          'orderby' => 'name',
          'show_count' => 0,
          'pad_counts' => 0,
          'hierarchical' => 1,
          'taxonomy' => $tax,
          'title_li' => ''
        );
        wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have 2 select element. First: department and second: doctors. Your code structure same as:

```
<select id="dep" name="dep">
  <option value="">Select Department</option>
  <option value="?department={DEP_ID}" selected="selected">Cardiac Clinic</option>
  <option value="?department={DEP_ID2}" selected="selected">Gynaecological Clinic</option>
</select>
```

And your select auto submit form with GET method. You can make it this jQuery:
Of course, you must have jQuery Library.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      $('#dep').bind('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val();
          if (url) {
              window.location = url;
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

And edit this page php source same as this:

```
  $list = array();
  if(isset($_GET['department'])){
    // get your posts by term

    $args = array(
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'department',
          'field' => 'id',
          'terms' => $_GET['dep']
        )
      )
    );
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );

    foreach($postslist as $doctor)
      $list[] = array("ID" => $doctor->ID, "title" => $doctor->post_title );
      // add doctors to list
  } else {
    $list[] = array("ID" => 0, "title" => "Select department first");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks SARI, but I want to have 2 select option in 1 page. When I select "deparment option" then "Doctor Option" change. Do you understand?